# How to validate input type="password"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I use the following Jquery Script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required:true
            },
            password: {
                required:true   
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and the html code:

```
<form id="myForm">
        <div id="box-header">
            <p>Username</p>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="required">
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
</form>
```

And my Problem is, that if Username is empty , the tooltip says "Cant be empty", but if the Password is empty, nothing happens, i also want this to apply to my password input?

Is anything wrong with the Jquery-Code?

Comment: add required attribute to `<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">`

Comment: AHhhh how stupid from me, thx for the quick response.Do you also know how i can style this "Error"-Messages?

Comment: Note that the `required` attribute does not need a value, it simply needs to exist (e.g. `<input type="text" required>`). You cannot reliably style the popup messages in all browsers AFAIK.

Comment: @lolio you can specify custom messages by `messages: {username: "your_message" }`

Comment: @OzgurBar, how does that matter when the OP has already declared the `required` rule on the password field via the `.validate()` method?

Comment: Your code is working just fine.  Since you've already declared the `required` rule within the `.validate()` method, you **do not** need the inline `required` attribute.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/jppz52c6/

Comment: @Sparky you're right. i think somehow i thought about `data-rule-required` attr in bootstrap for a sec. argh, thanks for the info though:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"And my Problem is, that if Username is empty , the tooltip says 'Cant be empty', but if the Password is empty, nothing happens"*

The big clue here is the word "tooltip".  This tells me that you've failed to initialize or include [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org), because there are no tooltips as part of this plugin.  Without the plugin, your code simply falls back to HTML5 validation (*where tooltips are created by the browser, not JavaScript/jQuery*)... which is triggered by the inline `required` attribute... which you only have on the `username` field.

However, if you properly [include the jQuery Validate plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js), then everything is working as you've programmed it.

Include the plugin after including jQuery...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Notice that you do not need the inline required attribute when declaring rules within the `.validate()` method:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

**DEMO using jQuery Validate plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/jppz52c6/**

---

**OTHERWISE**, if you'd just rather use [HTML5 validation](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/), then you don't need the `.validate()` method, nor would you even need any jQuery/JavaScript.  You'd just need to have inline HTML5 validation attributes (such as `required="required"`) on every field...

```
<input type="text" required="required" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
<input type="password" required="required" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

**DEMO using HTML5 validation:  http://jsfiddle.net/jppz52c6/1/**

**NOTE**:  HTML5 validation requires that the [browser support HTML5 validation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) and the tooltips will render differently in every browser.

Answer (score 1):

Add required attribute to your password input field

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
```

Comment: How does this solve anything when the OP has already declared `required` for this field within `.validate()`?  OP's code is working without your suggestion:  http://jsfiddle.net/jppz52c6/